# Save bmp to dictionary c#

Tags: c#, dictionary, bmp

I'm trying to save bmp file to dictionary
im using this code

```
Dictionary<string,MemoryStream> dict = new Dictionary<string,MemoryStream>();

dict.Add("mypicture.png",new MemoryStream());

image.Save(dict["mypicture.png"]);
```

but for some reason, i have an error in the last sentence
i dont know why, is there a missing parameter that i should add in the last function?

Comment: What is the exception that you get?

Comment: Because your `dict["mypicture.png"]` doesn't contain `png` image. You just created empty `MemoryStream`.

Comment: ...and then attempted to save an image into it.

Comment: Is it a BMP as stated in your question text, or is it a PNG as stated in your code? It's probably also worth telling us a bit about your variable `image`. What is it?

Comment: @HamletHakobyan: What is your point? The OP is saving, not loading.

Comment: It says " the best overload method match for 'system.drawing.image.save(string) ' has some invalid arguments
i need my picture to be in bmp format by the way i tried this image.Save(dict["mypicture.png"], ImageFormat.Png); but it gives me another error it says " imageformat does not exist in the current context " –

Comment: variable image is just a bmp image

Comment: That's its class? "a bmp image"? I don't think so.

Comment: okay i solved the problem, i missed a library
but now can i have one more question ?
if i want to access this memory stream
i have a function that takes in the file name
but when i put the filename it shows that this parameter is not valid
how to access this image now? after saving it to the memorystream
also if you can tell me how to release or delete this image from the memorystream after using it, how?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
image.Save(dict["mypicture.png"], ImageFormat.Png);
```

Don't forget include the library

```
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
```

Here is how you can define your image format:

```
if (ImageFormat.Jpeg.Equals(image.RawFormat))
{
    // JPEG
}
else if (ImageFormat.Png.Equals(image.RawFormat))
{
    // PNG
}
else if (ImageFormat.Bmp.Equals(image.RawFormat))
{
    // BMP
}
```

So the best solution is

```
 image.Save(dict["mypicture.bmp"], image.RawFormat);
```

Comment: It says " the best overload method match for 'system.drawing.image.save(string) ' has some invalid arguments

Comment: i need my picture to be in bmp format 
by the way i tried this 
image.Save(dict["mypicture.png"], ImageFormat.Png);
but it gives me another error
it says " imageformat does not exist in the current context "

Comment: Add using System.Drawing.Imaging;

Comment: can i have one last question ?
if i want to access this memory stream
i have a function that takes in the file name
but when i put the filename it shows that this parameter is not valid
how to access this image now? after saving it to the memorystream
also if you can tell me how to release or delete this image from the memorystream after using it, how?